# How can I seach for multiple values of a single field in youtrack?

Tags: youtrack

I'm trying to do the equivalent of a "where in" search in youtrack. I have a list of values and I want to know how to do that other than just saying:

```
field: value or field: value2 or field: value3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shortcut form would be #value1 #value2 #value3. The thing is that when you enumerate several values belonging to the same catogory (say, values of a field), the values are ORed.

Comment: I guess I just wasn't paying attention when I tried that.